# Websphere Scheduler

Tags: websphere, scheduler

Websphere Scheduler is using scheduler datasource XA driver . When task is executed by scheduler it is starting a global transaction, but in our application we are creating a new connection to another database and explicitly commiting the data and closing the connection. This data source configured using non-XA driver datasource. For the application we have also enabled the Accept heuristic hazard (Last participant support extension) . 
Now while running the scheudler we are getting the exception DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.commit is not allowed during a global transaction .

Can any one help me out in this

Comment: Why are you explicitly committing the other resource?  It is being enlisted in the tran started by the scheduler; it will automatically commit when the tran commits.

Answer (score 3):

Your task runs in a transaction and probably you call commit in that transaction. So you should call your db operations, commit and close db outside that transaction.
Create bean-managed transaction session bean

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
```

and move db and transaction related code into the new bean.